# WPF: Close and open windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

In my case I have a main window and a login view.

When the main window is closed, the login window should be displayed. I close it like so:

```
    void CloseOnCompleteAndDisplayLogin(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        new Login().Show();
    }
```

In the login window I open the `MainWindow` like so:

```
this.Hide();
var window = new MainWindow(model).Show();
```

**Problem**: When I login and open the `MainWindow` the first time it works fine. When I close the `MainWindow` and login again, several functions of the main window stop working or start throwing exceptions.

What am I doing wrong here? I already figured that `Window_Loaded` like events are not triggered on the re-login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Loaded` is  **not triggered** if you Hide/Show. Instead use the `Shown` event to initialize your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could be the problem

```
       new Login().Show();
```

first you hide your instance of login  window and after closing MainWindow you always create new()